# Cocos2D - node vs alloc/init

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

What's the difference between the following two lines?

1.

```
[CCLayer node]
```

2.

```
[[CCLayer alloc] init]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`[CCLayer node]` returns an **autoreleased** object.

`[[CCLayer alloc] init]` returns an **non-autoreleased** object

Comment: If you're using ARC then I think they're both autoreleased objects.

Comment: @PaulSlocum, this question was asked before ARC, but your comment has some warrant. ARC doesn't **have** to make them autoreleased, it just has to put the releases in the right place. What's important is that you no longer have to worry :)

Answer (score 5):

James got it right, but I just want to add that OP could just look into `CCNode.m` (or simply context-clicking on `node` in Xcode and choose "Jump to Definition") to find the following method implementation:

```
#pragma mark CCNode - Init & cleanup

+(id) node
{
    return [[[self alloc] init] autorelease];
}
```

So, `[CCLayer node]` is equivalent to `[[[CCLayer alloc] init] autorelease]`.